# How to track back which error occurred during DEPOLARIZE mechanism in a stim circuit

Tags: error-correction, stim

Suppose I create a circuit, which applies depolarizing error to a single qubit with probability 0.04.

```python
circuit = stim.Circuit()
    circuit.append_operation("H",0)
    circuit.append_operation("DEPOLARIZE1",0,0.04)
    circuit.append_operation("MR",0)
```

Now, I sample measurements as

```python
circuit.compile_sampler().sample(1)
```

Is it possible to track back which of the Pauli errors occurred during the sampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/536) to add this to Stim, so no it doesn't exist.

At the moment, the closest you can get is to sample the detector error model using `circuit.detector_error_model().compile_sample().sample(record_errors=True)` then convert those errors into corresponding circuit errors using `circuit.explain_detector_error_model_errors`. The downside of this is that the dem error doesn't uniquely identify circuit errors; there are multiple possible ways to get the same symptoms. It's also just generally more steps and more complications than really needed.

Part of the reason this isn't a priority is because in actual experiments you don't get access to this information.